# minimum investment required during ICO?

Tags: solidity, transactions, tokens, ico

how and where to set minimum investment in ETH & BTC in ERC20 contract ? done lots of google search but cant able to find the suitable article or tutorial how to place it in !

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to have a look at the libraries and contracts of [OpenZeppelin](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity) and [Crowdsale example](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/examples/SampleCrowdsale.sol).

These have been well tested, audited and adhere to security best practices.

Override the validPurchase method in your own Crowdsale contract to implement a min. investment limit.

```
function validPurchase() internal returns (bool) {
    bool moreThanMinimalInvestment = msg.value >= 0.1 ether; // change the value to whatever you need
    return super.validPurchase() && moreThanMinimalInvestment
}
```